# How to use Page.on("filechooser") to upload file in playwright

Tags: python, playwright

code like:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
viewport={"width":1920,"height":1080}
p = sync_playwright().__enter__()
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False,chromium_sandbox=True)
context = browser.new_context(viewport=viewport)
page = context.new_page()
page.goto("https://zh-cn.imgbb.com/")

page.on("filechooser",lambda f:f.set_files("picture.png")) #1
page.click(".home-buttons>a") #2
```

It dosen't work, How should I do to fix it?
And I feel confuse that code #2 dosen't open the source window.
but when I change code to :

```
page.click(".home-buttons>a") #2
page.on("filechooser",lambda f:f.set_files("picture.png")) #1
```

code #2 will open the source window.
Why the order of code #1 #2 could affect the page.click() operation?

Comment: Did you check https://playwright.dev/python/docs/input#upload-files ?

Answer (score 0):

***Select one file***

```
await page.get_by_label("Upload file").set_input_files('myfile.pdf')
```

***Select multiple files***

```
await page.get_by_label("Upload files").set_input_files(['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'])
```

***Remove all the selected files***

```
await page.get_by_label("Upload file").set_input_files([])
```

***Upload buffer from memory***

```
await page.get_by_label("Upload file").set_input_files(
    files=[
        {"name": "test.txt", "mimeType": "text/plain", "buffer": b"this is a test"}
    ],
)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how to use [Page.on('filechooser')](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-event-file-chooser), but instead explains [set-input-files](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-set-input-files). _(Note that `on('filechooser')` tests if the file dialog is opened e.g. when a "select file" button is clicked, which `set-input-files` wouldn't test.)_